# Right way of creating own UserControls in WPF (Csharp)

Tags: wpf, controls

I have moral question :)
I am creating my own controls (deriving UserControl) in WPF. Now there are two ways:

1. I am using one xaml and one cs file and have there all my stuff
2. I am loyal to MVVM and create one xaml and cs file for user control plus one cs file for its View Model and I am using MVVM technique.
   Then I have use my control like this:
   In xaml:

   ```
   <ContentControl Content={Binding MyControl....
   ```

   In code:

   ```
   MyControl = new MyControlViewModel()
   ```

Till now I used second approach but now I am reading some wise articles and it seems that many ppl uses first. 
So should I mix view and logic while creating controls? Of course I keep MVVM in other parts of app (I try to keep all logic stuff in view model). Couse I am afraid that my cs file will be too long.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that, as a rule of thumb, anything that requires an explicit VM is not just a control, it's already a kind of component. The controls should be fairly simple and have no advanced business logic.

Well, so if you see your code needs a VM, you can say that you have written a component, so there's no problem in having a separate VM class for it.

Comment: Thank you Vlad for that answer. I now realize that I don't really want to create new control :) Please check my new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557193/right-way-to-put-few-usercontrol-components-on-a-window

Comment: You are welcome! For your new question, I second Tendlon's answer: use the "small" VMs for the menu and main stuff, and put them into the main window's VM. Using Prism seems to be an overkill for small applications without plugins.